# installing Ubuntu on an older laptop gives me an error message

Tags: installation, lubuntu

The truth is that I cannot even start the installation. The live CD is loading and all of a sudden it is ejected and this message pops up:
unmount: /run/lock/: not mounted

It's an AVERATEC laptop and has a 1.50 Ghz Intel Pentium M processor and 504 Mb RAM.

The disk should be just fine, since I've already done the installation with it (it's Lubuntu 11.10 desktop i386). The checksum all worked out well on the iso and on the disc too. 
Now, what I did...I ticked all the first 3 options (acpi=off, noapic, noalpic) using F6 before on the installation screen to facilitate the installation. Now I've got the OS on the laptop, but after the installation I had to follow desgua's instructions and make the "acpi=off, noapic, noalpic" changes permanent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**

At boot time, try to press F6 and add one, two or these 3 commands: `acpi=off noapic noalpic`

That is:
`acpi=off noapic noalpic`, or
`acpi=off noalpic`, or
`acpi=off noapic`, or
`noapic noalpic`, or
`acpi=off`, or
`noapic`, or
`noalpic`

**Second**

After the installation has completed, you will have to edit grub to add the command needed.

As pointed by [fossfreedom](https://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom):

**"** 
To edit Grub2 during the boot process try the following:

1. Immediately after the BIOS splash screen during boot, press and hold the SHIFT button.  This will display you grub containing a list of kernels and recovery options
   [image]
2. Press e to edit the first kernel displayed
   [image]
3. Find the line ending with "quiet splash".  Add your boot option before these key words - i.e. so the line looks like ..."acpi=off noapic noalpic quiet splash"
4. Press CTRL + X to boot

**"**

**Third**

After successfully booting in your system, you can edit grub to turn the options permanent.

Paste on a terminal `gksudo leafpad /etc/default/grub`

Look for `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and change it for something like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=off noapic noalpic quiet splash"`.  Save and close.

Finally run `sudo update-grub`.

Enjoy ;-)